# Cannot read property $scope.dropdownfield of null in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple registration form page.
The form page have a person_id field and drop down list name condition_code_1. Person_id field is mandatory field meanwhile the condition_code_1 drop down list is an optional field mean's that it is optional for user to be selected or not. The value of the drop down list is fetched through specialConds array that data are get from oracle db field.

I stored the value of drop down list in data array in Condition_code_1 controller.The problem is when i do not select the list and submitted the form, angularjs throws an error : Cannot read property 'condCode1' of null. How do i ignored the drop down list when it is not selected. Any help here.

**1) Condition_code_1 list**

```
  <select id = "condition_code_1"
          data-placeholder = "Please select"   
          ng-model         = "specialCond.condCode1"
          ng-options       = "t.condCode as t.condDesc for t in specialConds" chosen>
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
  </select>
```

**2) Condition_code_1 Controller**

```
 $scope.create = function () {
    var data = {};

    data.personId = $scope.person_id;
    data.conditionCode1 = $scope.specialCond.condCode1; 

    CondCodeSvc.create(data, function(res){
           jAlert('Create successfull');
    }, errSvc.errorHandler);                   
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because *data* doesn't exist before you call $scope.create(), therefore is undefined, which means is not an object, which means it cannot have a property, thus javascript throws the error.

try:

```
var data = {};
$scope.create = function () {

    data.personId = $scope.person_id;
    data.conditionCode1 = $scope.specialCond.condCode1; 

    CondCodeSvc.create(data, function(res){
       jAlert('Create successfull');
    }, errSvc.errorHandler);                   
};
```

Comment: I 've found the solution. It is not the data. It is $scope.specialCond is not existed. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Hey, good to hear you found a solution. It is not mine though, so you shouldn't accept my answer since it misleads other people who come here trying to find an answer to the same problem you had. You should instead post your solution as an answer and accept that! If you still want to "reward" my contribution you can just do a +1. Thanks anyway and good luck!